# I can't create folder or share images on android 11

Tags: android, image, directory, share

How can create folder or share images on android 11 ?
This the First code for save file or image:

```
     @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            path = args[0];
            String idStr = path.substring (path.lastIndexOf ('/') + 1);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();
            File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath () + "/MyDownloads/");
            dir.mkdirs ();
            String fileName = idStr;
            Ion.with (getApplicationContext ()).load (path)
                    .write (new File (dir, fileName));

            return null;
        }
```

And this is the Second for share:

```
 @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            path = args[0];
            String idStr = path.substring (path.lastIndexOf ('/') + 1);
            File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ();
            File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath () + "/MyDownloads/");
            dir.mkdirs ();
            String fileName = idStr;
            file = new File (dir, fileName);
            Ion.with (getApplicationContext ()).load (path)
                    .write (file);
            return null;
        }
```

Please I am waiting your help.

Comment: Directly on root of external storage will not go. Try the folders that are already there on external storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't know how Iam a new developer.

Comment: Please name a few directories that are already on root of external storage.

Comment: Try `File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath () + "/Download/MyDownloads/");`

Comment: Only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet. And if you do check the return value.

Comment: Waaaaw thank you very much it's very sweet from you, you saved me, Can we be friend may be working together?

Comment: I should learn more about call mkdirs or check the return value haha lol, but the problem is resolved by you thank you again, I need a developer like you if you like thank you a million times.